Conda package conflicts while exporting Tensorflow trained model into ONNX
I used these instructions to build up a conda env and train tensorflow model:
conda create --name tf210 python=3.8
conda activate tf210
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0
pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.10.0 keras==2.10.0 
pip install opencv-python==4.4.0.44 pillow==8.2 numpy==1.22 matplotlib scipy pandas scikit-learn tqdm imutils PyYAML tensorboard seaborn protobuf==3.20 chardet

pip install tensorflow-datasets==4.6.0
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tf210 --display-name="tf210"

conda install -c conda-forge widgetsnbextension ipywidgets

The env worked well and I trained my MNIST model, but when I try to install the package below, my code reported errors. I wonder how can I fix this problem and export my tensorflow model directly into ONNX model.
pip install tf2onnx
pip install onnxruntime

Here is the error log:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\pythonProject\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf210\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets import image
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf210\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\image\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from tensorflow_datasets.image.dsprites import Dsprites
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf210\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_datasets\image\dsprites.py", line 23, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\tf210\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import _errors
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _errors:The specified program cannot be found.

I searched the Internet and tried to find out which package is in conflict, but I failed. It seems that all the packages in my conda list are correct except the protobuf 3.20.3, but there is an answer in Stackoverflow that shows protobuf 3.20.x is the only suitable version for tensorflow-gpu 2.10.0 and tensorboard 2.14.0.
I wonder if I can still use tensorflow-gpu 2.10.0 and exported my tensorflow model into ONNX model, yet I haven't figure out where the conflict is. I would be appreciated if anyone answers my question. Tell me if there is more details and information needed.

Hi, this seems to be the problem with dependences between multiple packages. In python we need to take care of such issue. One suggestion in this regards is to install the h5py 3.7.0 package and then install tf2onnx 1.10 and onnxruntime 1.12 version. This will resolve the dependencies problem you are facing right now.

At first, I reinstalled the whole env, uninstalled and reinstalled the h5py=3.7.0, but I found that in my conda list the version of h5py was still 3.11.0, and while I installed the tensorflow-datasets, the code reported the same error without tf2onnx installation.
In the second round, I did the same job and it is weird that this time the code ran successfully. Nothing happened even I install the tf2onnx and onnxruntime, so I suspect that the problem might be the conflict between tensorflow-datasets and h5py.
